# Simplifying a Java if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I want some help converting this Java code to an if/else statement.

```
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    boolean result = true;
    if (level != null ? !level.equals(log.level) : log.level != null)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is truly terrible code: It's full of double negatives! No wonder you want to make it readable.

(I think) this is what it should be:

```
return log.level == null || log.level.equals(level);
```

Note that parameter `obj` is ignored (?)

Answer (score 2):

Bohemian notes this:

> Note that parameter obj is ignored (?)

Now, the method as given in the Question overrides the standard `equals(Object)`, and that method is supposed to implement specified semantics; see the javadoc for [Object.equals(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Furthermore, this version of `equals(Object)` quite obviously does NOT implement those semantics.  (How can `x.equals(y)` test if `x` is equal to `y` if it doesn't refer to `y` ?)

So my advice to the OP is to fix this broken equals method, and whatever depends on the method having these broken semantics ... rather than just trying to make the method more readable.

---

If this isn't the real code (i.e. if this is NOT an `equals(Object)` method at all) then I've just wasted a good rant.

Answer (score 1):

May be worth trying to ask yourself in English under what circumstances you want to return true or false. Then just translate that to Java.

In the code you provided, you're returning true unless:

- level isn't null, and level is not log.level
- level is null, and log level isn't null

Try flipping that around and turning the "unless" into an "if":
Return true *if*:

- level is null and so is log.level
- level isn't null, but level equals log.level

In Java, this becomes:

```
if (level == null)
{
    return log.level == null;
}
else
{
    return level.equals(log.level);
}
```

Or, more simply:

```
return level == null ? log.level == null : level.equals(log.level);
```

With all that said, that's not really how you want the equals(Object obj) method to work. That method should return whether obj is equal to this, and in the code you've provided, you're not asking any questions about obj. You're answering a different question than the one equals(Object) requires you to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) and the given expression can be written as:

```
if (level != null) {
    if(!level.equals(log.level)) {
        result = false;
    }
} else {
    if(log.level != null) {
        result = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
  boolean result = true;

  if (level != null)
  {
    if(!level.equals(log.level) 
    {
      result = false;
    }
  } 
  else
  {
    if(log.level != null)
    {
      result = false;
    }

  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    boolean result = true;

    if (level != null) {
        result = level.equals(log.level);
    } else {
        result = log.event != null;
    }

    return result;
}
```